# sqlalchemy load column name and table twice

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I wrote a code to connect sqlalchemy to clickhose .the problem is when i print querystatement, table name loaded twice in it! what do sqlalchemy exactly that cause this problem ? does anyone had this problem before?

my code :

```
session.query(className)
```

query.statement:

```
select a,b from table_name, table_name
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this (but I don't have access to clickhouse): can you provide a runnable example? Can you reproduce with other RDBMS, for example SQLite?

Comment: i have to connect to clickhose

Comment: how can i provide a runnable example

Comment: Which driver/library do you use to connect to clickouse ? This : https://pypi.org/project/clickhouse-sqlalchemy/ ?

Comment: Does this occur when you apply a filter (applying a `.where()` or `.filter()`) method) ?

Comment: @jossefaz yes i use this driver

Comment: @jossefaz no it's before filter